# Apple Developer Program - problema en el registro

Tags: certificado-apple

Al iniciar el proceso de subscripción en Apple Development Program, me muestra el siguiente mensaje: **Your enrollment could not be completed.** y no permite continuar con el proceso. A continuación se presenta una captura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se contactó con el equipo de Apple y proponen responder en uno o dos días, alguien más ha tenido algún inconveniente parecido ? y si tiene alguna idea de como solucionarlo seria de mucha ayuda. De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: Ingresaste todos los datos, incluídos los de tu tarjeta de crédito?

Comment: No, solo pude acceder hasta la primera pagina de registro, donde piden solo datos básicos, no me permitió acceder a la pagina donde se ingresa la tarjeta de credito

Comment: Puedes adjuntar una captura de los datos que te piden en el registro. Déjalos en blanco.

Comment: No me permite regresar, ya que parece que guarda el proceso de resgistro, incluso si cierro la cuenta y vuelvo a entrar, me redirige a la pagina donde muestra el mensaje: "Your enrollment could not be completed"

Comment: Creo que lo mejor en este caso sería tratar de usar otra cuenta con la que no exista conflicto, porque debe ser algún dato ingresado el que esta causando el problema

Comment: Posiblemente. Si lo solucionas lo comentas para que sirva de ayuda para los que puedan tener el mismo problema.

Comment: Listo, gracias por la ayuda, tratare de usar otra cuenta por lo pronto.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  es una pregunta para el soporte de Apple.

Comment: Ok gracias por tu ayuda Shaz

Answer (score 0):

Unas horas luego de contactar al equipo de apple, me ayudaron con la solución, que había sido por inconsistencias de verificación según lo que me comunicaron a travez de email, dándome la posibilidad de acceder de nuevo a la pagina de ingreso de datos para proceder con el proceso de inscripción. Muchas gracias por su ayuda.